# Using before() and after() with anchors

Tags: jquery

i have a img

```
<img id="dynamic" src="www.google.com.br" />
```

How can i use the before() and after() methods of jquery to set an anchor in that img?

Like this:

```
$('#dynamic').before('<a href="http://google.com">');
$('#dynamic').after('</a>');
```

But... when i do something like this, jquery automatically add the close tag of the anchor

```
<a href="http://google.com"></a>
<img id="dynamic" src="www.google.com.br" />
```

Some idea?

Comment: you are looking for wrap()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery DOM addition functions like `append`, `before`, `after`, etc. don't edit the HTML as a string but append valid DOM fragments made of elements. That's why you can't just append something like `</a>`, that would make the DOM invalid.

What you want is to [wrap](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) your element :

```
$('#dynamic').wrap('<a href="http://google.com"/>');
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't append part of an element.

```
$('#dynamic').before('<a href="http://google.com">');
```

generates a whole element and

```
$('#dynamic').after('</a>');
```

generates a whole element (or none at all, depending on browser).

Use the `.wrap` method.

```
$('#dynamic').wrap('<a href="http://google.com"></a>');
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`.wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) instead:

```
$('#dynamic').wrap('<a href="http://google.com"></a>');
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$('#dynamic').wrap('<a href="http://google.com"/>');
```